# Pictures not displayed in 'Photos' App

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am very new to Android development!

I am working on a camera-related app, and I encountered a problem that the pictures taken are not immediately displayed in 'Photos' app in Android 5.0.1, but when I restart the phone, and take a picture one more time, the previous pictures would all be displayed in 'Photos' app. And this problem only occurs in Android 5.0.1. I tried it on Android 4.3, and there isn't the problem.
And I do add the following codes in my program:

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM")); //out is your output file
                mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}`

Could anybody help me out there please????